# Why is process.debugPort defined when not debugging?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I've been exploring the various ways to detect whether a node process has a debugger attached or not. I came across the straightforward looking [`process.debugPort`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_debugport), which is documented as:

> **process.debugPort**
>
> Added in: v0.7.2
>
> - <number>
>
> The port used by the Node.js debugger when enabled.

What do the docs mean by "when enabled"? Or perhaps more to the point, when is the debugger not enabled? A simple test program shows that the `process.debugPort` always seems to be defined.

```
'use strict'

const debugPort = process.debugPort
console.log(`debugPort: ${debugPort}`)
```

Here is some command line output showing its invocation in node v10.22.1 – I tested node v15.3.0 and observed the same behavior.

```
➜  node --version
v10.22.1
➜  node nodeDebug.js 
debugPort: 9229
➜  node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9999 nodeDebug.js
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9999/db5cdb75-4745-4ea1-9a87-3f81c811c563
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
debugPort: 9999
```

So even when invoking node without a --inspect flag, the debugPort is defined (and set to the default of 9229).

---

As an aside, the best method I've discovered for detecting whether node is in debugging mode or not is [`inspector.url()`](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#inspector_inspector_url) which

> Return the URL of the active inspector, or undefined if there is none.

I'm not sure if this is bulletproof, but it covers my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you start without the explicit `--inspect` flag, it's always possible to enable the inspector on an ad hoc basis by sending the process a SIGUSR1 signal like so:

```sh
kill -SIGUSR1 $myNodePID
```

As such, it makes sense that the `debugPort` property is always set to something, as it's possible that it might be shortly used.

See towards top of [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) for passing sentence confirming this.

Comment: That makes sense. I skimmed through the debugger doc you linked yesterday. But it doesn't answer if the debugger can be disabled, or why the `debugPort` documentation would imply that it could be disabled.

Comment: But it is disabled most of the time - and while disabled the port isn't used to listen for connections. Though it's always possible for it to be suddenly switched on! And this means the setting specifying which port _would_ be used to listen must always be set. DebugPort being set (and it always is) doesn't mean the debugger is actually listening at that moment.

Comment: Another way of putting it: the debugger is always initialised (with no way of sidestepping this without recompiling Node), but usually not turned on

Comment: Can the Node process reserve the port without actively listening for connections on it? I was assuming not, and there was a risk of the port getting taken by a different process, but if that's not the case, then it suddenly makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Just checked this by running two node processes like so: `node -e 'setInterval(() => console.log(process.debugPort), 1000)'` and then sending SIGUSR1 to each - they're both set to use 9229 by default, and if debugging is turned on on one, the other will log an error when you send the magic signal to it - the ports aren't reserved!